How to use contextMenuBuilder in EditableText?
I am trying to create a subclass of EditableText but ran into the issue that EditableTextState.showToolbar() does not use my contextMenuBuilder but builds a default menu. How can make it use contextMenuBuilder without using another text widget like TextField?
Here is a simple test version which runs into the same issue.
class TestPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  TestPageState createState() => TestPageState();

  final TextEditingController textController = TextEditingController();
}

class TestPageState extends State<TestPage> {
  final GlobalKey<EditableTextState> editableTextKey = GlobalKey<EditableTextState>();
  final FocusNode focusNode = FocusNode();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(30.0),
      child: EditableText(
        key: editableTextKey,
        backgroundCursorColor: Colors.black,
        rendererIgnoresPointer: false,
        selectionControls: materialTextSelectionControls,
        enableInteractiveSelection: true,
        showSelectionHandles: true,
        selectionColor: Colors.purple.withOpacity(0.3),
        onSelectionChanged: (TextSelection selection, SelectionChangedCause? cause) {
          EditableTextState? editableText = editableTextKey.currentState;

          if (editableText != null) {
            editableText.showToolbar();
            print("Toolbar shown");
          } else {
            print("Error showing toolbar");
          }
        },
        controller: widget.textController,
        focusNode: focusNode,
        contextMenuBuilder: (BuildContext context, EditableTextState editableTextState) {
          print("contextMenuBuilder ran");
          
          List<ContextMenuButtonItem> buttonItems = [
            ContextMenuButtonItem(
              onPressed: () {
                print("Custom button pressed");
              },
              label: 'Custom Button',
            ),
          ];

          buttonItems.addAll(editableTextState.contextMenuButtonItems);

          return AdaptiveTextSelectionToolbar.buttonItems(
            anchors: editableTextState.contextMenuAnchors,
            buttonItems: buttonItems,
          );
        },
        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 30),
        cursorColor: Colors.blue,
      ),
    );
  }
}

